# Sudden FPS drop with nouveau drivers in Debian Testing desktop (becomes unusable)

Tags: debian, nvidia, nouveau

I'm trying to debug this issue but I'm quite lost.

Some weeks ago, I was running Debian testing Buster with Nvidia 340 legacy drivers (GeForce GTX 260) and everything worked flawlessly.

Debian got updated to Bullseye, and Nvidia driver is not compatible yet, so I had to switch to Nouveau.

Since then, I cannot get 1 hour without my system almost freezing. When it happens get at most **1 frame every 2 or 3 seconds**. Sometimes it happens after only a few minutes, others it allows me to work for longer. If I reboot (which is not easy at that framerate), everything goes back to normal.

How can I debug this issue? Where can I look for logs to pinpoint the cause?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dmesg` might show you some useful information when the system slows down.

Comment: Reading last boot dmesg from `/var/log/kern.log` I get a lot of `nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: base-1: timeout` every 2 seconds from the moment system freezes...